# My ant build file crashes on start

Tags: xml, ant, build

I Get this error when I try and run the .xml file build that I have created. I did not originally create this code. There was this tutorial online and I used it. I have tried to contact the owner but he won't reply

```
Build Failed
Delete doen't support the "di" attribute
```

It has to do with this code:

```
<delete di="${build.dir.development}\forge\mcp\reobf\minecraft" />
```

Here is all the code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
    <project name="Top" default="build">
    <!-- Files which hold information -->
    <property file="build.properties" prefix="build"/>
    <property file="build_number.properties" prefix="build_number"/>

    <!-- Delete files which were used in previous build -->
    <target name="clean">
        <delete file="${build.dir.development}\forge\mcp\src\minecraft\mcmod.info" />
        <delete dir="${build.dir.development}\forge\mcp\src\minecraft\com\NoobMod" />
        <delete di="${build.dir.development}\forge\mcp\reobf\minecraft" />
    </target>

    <!-- Increment build number -->
    <target name="increment_build_number">
        <propertyfile file="build_number.properties">
            <entry key="build_number" type="int" operation="+" default="1"/>
        </propertyfile>
    </target>

    <!-- Copy your project to MCP-->
    <target name="prep">
        <copy todir="${build.dir.development}\forge\mcp\src\minecraft">
            <fileset dir="${build.dir.development}\source\NoobMod\common"/>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <!-- Recompile and Reobfuscate your project inside /MCP -->
    <target name="recompile">
        <exec dir="${build.dir.development}\forge\mcp" executable="cmd" osfamily="windows">
            <arg line="/c recompile.bat" />
        </exec>
        <exec dir="${build.dir.development}\forge\mcp" executable="bash" osfamily="unix">
            <arg line="recompile.sh" />
        </exec>
    </target>

    <target name="reobfuscate">
        <exec dir="${build.dir.development}\forge\mcp" executable="cmd" osfamily="windows">
            <arg line="/c reobfuscate_srg.bat" />
        </exec>
        <exec dir="${build.dir.development}\forge\mcp" executable="bash" osfamily="unix">
            <arg line="reobfuscate_srg.sh" />
        </exec>
    </target>

    <!-- THE ACTUAL BUILDING PART -->
    <!-- The actual build, where we call the targets -->
    <target name="build">
        <!-- Prep for the build -->
        <antcall target="clean" />
        <antcall target="increment_build_number" />
        <antcall target="prep" />
        <antcall target="recompile" />      
        <antcall target="reobfuscate" />

        <!-- Build the jar -->
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir.release}\${build.release.minecraft.version}\${build.release.mod.version}" />
        <jar destfile="${build.dir.release}\${build.release.minecraft.version}\${build.release.mod.version}\Noob Mod  -${build.release.mod.version}.jar">
            <fileset dir="${build.dir.development}\forge\mcp\src\minecraft\" includes="mcmod.info" />
            <fileset dir="${build.dir.development}\forge\mcp\reobf\minecraft" />
            <fileset dir="${build.dir.development}\source\NoobMod\resources" excludes="**/xcf/**" />
            <delete dir="${build.dir.development}\forge\mcp\src\minecraft\com\NoobMod" />
        </jar>

        <!-- Clean up the MCP source now that we are done -->
        <antcall target="clean" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the following line, change `di` to `dir`.

```
<delete di="${build.dir.development}\forge\mcp\reobf\minecraft" />
```

Above line is wrong as it uses `delete di`

Below is correct:

```
<delete dir="${build.dir.development}\forge\mcp\reobf\minecraft" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the xml version at the top

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

You can change the version to 2.0 if that suits you better.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call it *crashing*. It's more like not running due to a syntax error. Let's look at your error message:

> Build Failed
>   Delete doen't support the "di" attribute

As you discovered, it has to do with this line:

```
<delete di="${build.dir.development}\forge\mcp\reobf\minecraft" />
```

If you look up the [Delete Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html) in the online [Ant Manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual), you will see indeed that there is no `di` attribute.

There is a `dir` attribute which I assume that's what you really meant.